# How to remove an item from DropDownList If No is Selected on Bootstrap Modal?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, model-view-controller

Scenario:
User will select from a DropdownList.
Here is the Dropdown code:

```
     @Html.DropDownList("ddlRequestMade", new List<SelectListItem>
                                {
                                   new SelectListItem{ Text="Please Select", Value = "Please Select" },
                                   new SelectListItem{ Text="Stuff", Value = "Stuff" },
                                   new SelectListItem{ Text="Card", Value = "Card" },
                                }, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

If User Select 'Card' option in Dropdown, a Bootstrap Modal Appear:

Basic Modal code:

```
         <!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal" id="myModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <!-- Modal header -->
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title">Card?</h4>
            </div>
            <!-- Modal body -->
            <div class="modal-body">
                Confirm ?
            </div>
            <!-- Modal footer -->
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-dismiss="modal">Yes</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When User click on No, Modal should close, and preferably remove the 'Card' option from the dropdown list.
How can this be achieved using javascript?

Here is my js code to show the modal:

```
    $(function () {
    $("#ddlRequestMade").change(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == "Card") {
            $("#dvToShowOrHide").show();
            $("#dvToShowOrHideP2").show();
            $("#myModal").modal('show');
        } else {
            $("#dvToShowOrHide").hide();
            $("#dvToShowOrHideP2").hide();
        }
    });
});
$("button[data-dismiss=modal]").click(function () {
    $(".modal").modal('hide');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for remove option from select

```
$("button[data-dismiss=modal]").click(function () {
    $(".modal").modal('hide');
    $("#ddlRequestMade option[value='Card']").remove();
    $("#ddlRequestMade").val('Please Select');
});
```